# Show parent table of td , while hiding to filter that table for search

Tags: jquery

How can i edit this so my searchbar returns all the td content in a table that matches text letter i type in my input being filtered only by 1 of the td cells within that table "td.search-text". For example, i type in "Z" and i get all the td content from the table that td.search-text is filtered with. With my current script, i only get the td.search-text cell by itself and i want all other td within that table as well , but dont want to generalize the search for entire table , just the td.search-text text.

I have tried to add parent to this but could not get to work

```
$('table td.search-text').filter(':containsLower("'+this.value+'")').show().parent();
```

here is current html-jquery

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
            <td class="search-text this-cell-only">ZZZZZ</td>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
            <td class="search-text this-cell-only">AAAA</td>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
            <td class="search-text this-cell-only">BBBB</td>
            <td>Show Me if search of td.search-text matches</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

```
jQuery.expr[':'].containsLower = function(a, i, m) {
  if (m[3] === '') {
    return true;
  }
  var re = new RegExp('(^' + m[3].toUpperCase() + '[^ ]+) | (' + m[3].toUpperCase() + '.*$)');
  return a.textContent.toUpperCase().trim().match(re) != null;
};
$(function () {
  $('#search').keyup(function(){
    $('table td').hide();
    $('table td.search-text').filter(':containsLower("'+this.value+'")').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: jquery `.siblings()`? e.g. `$('table td.search-text').filter(':containsLower("'+this.value+'")').siblings().show()`. Your TD's are initially hidden (display:none), while your current code is setting the parent TR to show (`display:;`), in which case TD's still remain hidden. I'm guessing a little here...

Comment: using sibling only shows the other td cells and won't display the td cell for which the filtered search was applied to

Comment: Then add this to the mix: https://api.jquery.com/andself/

Comment: bingo that did it ty h2015 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function () {
$('#search').keyup(function(){
$('table').hide();
//alert('333');
$('table td.search-text:contains("'+$(this).val().toUpperCase()+'")').parent().parent().parent().show().siblings().not('div').hide();
});
});`

The above snippet would be helpful, use of `:contains()` on TD is more than enough

Use of 3 `parent()` coordinates to target, TR then tbody then table.

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5wb9m7s9/17/

Comment: that is still hiding all other td within the table , and it also disables the search from working

Comment: You mean, whichever TD content matches, the whole table should be displayed is it? Please confirm!

Comment: i want all td cells , withing the table to show , if td.show contains the matching search text https://jsfiddle.net/5wb9m7s9/6/